# Problems with bare domains and DNS load balancing?

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

Can using a bare domain as server address (i.e. using *example.com* not *www.example.com*) make DNS based load balancing harder in some manner?

Load balancing examples:

- [Round robin DNS load balancing](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/rr.html#services).
- [Split Horizon DNS Server](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch4/#split), that is, giving different responses (IP addresses) based on the client address.
- A planned feature of [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/): *"In the future, we plan to add additional integration features such as the ability to route your customers to the closest EC2 region."*

*Background:* Sometimes when people argue one should include *www* in the server address, instead of using a bare domain name as server address, they mention problems related to load balancing and bare domains. But they don't seem to specify what are those problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time you'll get problems is when you're using a third-party shared (or provider-managed GLB) load-balancing service, like Amazon's ELB, that requires you to put a CNAME to their load-balancing system into your DNS.  In that case, you won't be able to use your bare domain name, because you can't have a CNAME and another record type (such as NS or SOA) on the same rrname.

Comment: Interesting, I currently have a single Amazon EC2 instance. I suppose then that I'd better go with `www`, since in the future I'll probably use Amazon's Elastic Load Balancing.

Comment: This CNAME issue might actually be a rather huge problem for some people. [Here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=32044&start=100&tstart=0#jive-message-192846) is a terribly long thread discussing the issue with Amazon's ELB and (no) bare domains. In the thread, *dafaleiting* says that *"The top 10 sites on the Internet according to Alexa are: Google, Facebook, YouTube, Yahoo, Live, Baidu, Wikipedia, Blogger, Twitter, and MSN. Of those ten, eight will redirect queries made to their DNS root to www.company.com. Only Twitter and Baidu actually serve requests off the root DNS."*

Comment: It seems Amazon has a solution: *Amazon [...] has [...] in order to easily let you map your root domain (e.g., mydomain.com, without the ‘www’), directly to your Load Balancer.*, see: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1033

Comment: Amazon are probably doing shady-buggers with making an internal mapping between whatever IP your ELB has and your domain.  This will *only* work if you're using both Route 53 and ELB.  It doesn't help in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not make DNS load balancing any different.  In both cases you must specify the round-robin entries in your zone file.  Having www or '@' is a trivial difference.

Comment: Okay, interesting to know that you can have many `@` records (I was wondering if one could only have e.g. many `www` records), thanks.